# viewing XML data saved in BLOB Column via Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, arrays, blob

I read the data from BLOB in Oracle, then assign to an object as byte []. I know the data is UTF-8 encoded XML therefore create a big String from the raw byte array and write directly to the PrintWriter of the ServletResponse object.

The response is expected to be downloaded on the client browser side as an attachment. But 
the downloaded file is corrupt, the encoding is not correctly set in my opinion. Should I not set the HTTP Headers explicitly? I cannot figure out why I cannot reconstruct the XML as it is in the Database. any idea?

```
  String filename = data_src.getFilename() + ".xml";
  byte [] data = data_src.getByte_data();
  String xml_UTF_8 = new String(data, "UTF-8");


  // Init Servlet Response.
  response.reset();
  response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=utf-8");
  response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
  response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + xml_UTF_8.length() /*data.length ???*/);
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\""); //inline vs attachment 

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(xml_UTF_8);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } finally {
        //  close streams.
        response.flushBuffer();
    }

    // Inform JSF that it doesn't need to handle the response.
    // This is very important, otherwise you will get the following exception in the logs:
    // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed.
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}`
```

Comment: "But the downloaded file is corrupt" as in not UTF-8, or is it a different problem? Why are you calling `response.reset();` Did you print something already higher up?

Comment: yes first of all it is bigger in size than the size on DB, meaning extra bytes added meanwhile.  response.reset() is a good practice.I guess it compains about the "UTF-8" thing. I don't have control over the files put to the BLOB Column.

Comment: You should try just writing out each byte in the byte array rather than converting to string first.